# Confused by a summation inside the integral: $\int_0^1 (v-u)^2 \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u_i}{n}\delta_{i/n}(v) dv$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, dirac-delta

I came across the following integral:

$\int_0^1 (v-u)^2 \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u_i}{n}\delta_{i/n}(v) dv$,

where the deltas represent the Dirac delta distribution. How would one evaluate this integral? I got confused by the summation inside the integral. Any help would be grateful

Comment: You can interchange an integral with a finite sum freely, does that help you figure it out?

Comment: I know that rule but it hasn’t helped. Are you willing to show how this integral is solved?

Comment: Once you have done that you can just evaluate one Dirac delta integral after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the "delta function" isn't a funcion, right?  It is a Schwartz distribution, or generalized function.

The formulation
$$
\int_0^1 (v-u)^2 \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u_i}{n}\delta_{i/n}(v) dv
$$
involving the distribution $\delta$ should be taken as short-hand for:
$$
\int_0^1 (v-u)^2 \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u_i}{n}\delta_{i/n}(v) dv
=
\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u_i}{n}\int_0^1 (v-u)^2 \delta_{i/n}(v) dv
=
\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u_i}{n} \left(\frac{i}{n}-u\right)^2
$$
where the last one no longer involves distruibutions.

Maybe.

There is still the question about the values $i=0$ and $i=n$, where $\frac{i}{n}$ is an endpoint of the interval $[0,1]$.  Does your text have a convention about delta at an endpoint?  Maybe take half of those two terms?

Comment: Yess for the bounds we have to take half the terms

Comment: Are you able to continue solving the integral?

Comment: So for example, for the following integral $\int_0^1 v^2 \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u}{n} \delta_{i/n}(v) dv$ we obtain $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u}{n}(\frac{i}{n})^2$?

Comment: so, in this comment you changed $u$ to $0$ and $u_i$ to $u$.  And you did not use $(1/2)$ of the two end terms.

Comment: You are right; $u_i$ must be $u$, that was a mistake. However, I am not sure how to use these endpoints. Are you willing to show me that?